# Stop navigation AFTER link has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html

- I have a slider with some buttons (which are links).
- The buttons have double function
- If I click on an inactive button, the slider will slide to the appropriate slide and the button will turn active (so `preventDefault()` here)
- If I click on an active button, the link will work (no `preventDefault()`)

Now, when I click on another inactive link after an active link is clicked, the browser will still got to the active link's url.

So the question is: How can I abort/stop/cancel a link navigation, **after** the link was pressed? I.E. my browser is already working.
The question is **not**: How can I prevent the link to be followed, if I click on the link?

---

```
jQuery('a.button').on('click', function(e){
    if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        // no preventDefault(), so link is followed
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    // how can I stop the link from above?
    // ..
    jQuery(this).addClass('active')
    // do the slide thing
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is `window.stop()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop

> The stop() method is exactly equivalent to clicking the stop button in
>   the browser. Because of the order in which scripts are loaded, the
>   stop() method cannot stop the document in which it is contained from
>   loading, but it will stop the loading of large images, new windows,
>   and other objects whose loading is deferred.

Comment: This is good. Haven't thought of the window object. But ... do we have alternatives without stopping the loading of assets?

Comment: As stated in the description, this is pretty much just simulating the browser's `stop` button. Not sure if there are any plausible alternatives. Your biggest risk is calling this method before your current page is fully loaded; but if you can avoid that it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, of course. But what if the page is very long with many contents and I want the slide to work on `ready()` and not on `load()`?

Comment: Could set a flag on `load`, and only allow the `.stop()` functionality once the current page has fully loaded. Thats probably your best bet, given that the need for `.stop()` is more of an edge case to begin with.